# django migration with multiple languages

Tags: django

It seems `makemigrations` command is affected by django language (django.mo, django.po etc).

I have two projects. One is *upstream* and the other *origin* is forked version of upstream.

Upstream's LANGUAGE_CODE is `ko-kr` and that of origin is `en`. In upstream when I run `makemigrations`, provided that I have django.mo file under `locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES`, **no changes detected**.

Now I head to origin whose language is `en`. I have `locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo` file. When I run `makemigrations` I see a long list of migration files. But with a close look, *all* of them are about changes of verbose_name, choices label etc.

When one has django project that supports more than one languages, how does one make it recognise its language and prevent it from making unnecessary migration files?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.

When you change `LANGUAGE_CODE` amid project, you **mess it up**. Since django migration seems to care what locale your project is using, changing it can cause unnecessary migration files (verbose_name, help_text etc).

When I change my `LANGUAGE_CODE` from `en` **back** to `ko-kr`, which is the same as that of **upstream**, in **origin**'s settings, no additional migration files are generated. *No changes detected*!

Related links are as follow:

- [django forum](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/django-migration-files-with-many-languages/24458/3)
- [django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21498)

For translation by client refer to the followings:

- [LANGUAGE_CODE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-LANGUAGE_CODE)
- [How Django discovers language preference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference)
- [Accept-Language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language)